# Ruby split string, with exclusions

Tags: ruby, string, split

I want to take a string, and split by a substring unless that substring is prepended by a character of choice like `\`. It is easy to split by a string using the `split()` function, but what if I want to split by `' '` unless `'\ '`.

```
puts "this is a\ string".split(' ','\ ')
# => ["this", "is", "a string"]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not put your solution or an answer into your question. SO isn't a message list or forum, it's more like an online reference book of questions and their associated answers, and we keep the two separate. _If_ you intend your solution to be the selected answer, then create an appropriate answer, then, when SO says it's OK you can select it. As is, you should remove your edit. In addition, "thanks" is considered fluff and is very likely to be removed. "[ask]" and its linked pages explain all this. Also, the [tour] would be good for you.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, I just fixed it, good catch. Thanks.

Comment: Splitting is the way to go but you could alternatively `scan`: `'this is a\ string'.scan /\w+(?:\\ \w*)*/ #=> ["this", "is", "a\\ string"]`.

Comment: @MichaelSisko in Ruby, `"this is a\ string"` is equivalent to `"this is a string"`, i.e. the escape sequence  `"\ "` becomes a plain `" "`. You might want to change your example to include a literal backslash (use ``\\`` or single quotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split with a regular expression with a [negative lookbehind assertion](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors).

```rb
str = "this.is\\.a.string"
str.split(/(?<!\\)\./)
# => ["this", "is\.a", "string"]
```

> `(?<!pat)` - Negative lookbehind assertion: ensures that the preceding characters do not match pat, but doesn't include those characters in the matched text

Comment: How do I do this while excluding the slash character from the output set of strings?

Comment: @MichaelSisko Two options: 1) do a separate operation on the result of `split` or 2) use [scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-scan). The latter would be more performant, but more complicated to read.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex with negative look-behind:

```rb
'a b c\ d e'.split(/(?<!\\) /)
=> ["a", "b", "c\\ d", "e"]
```

The pattern `(?<!\\)`  matches spaces not preceded by a backslash.